# Image dialog — extend onOk, instead of total overwrite

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have found out that I can hook into `onOk` with this:

```
editor.on('dialogShow', function (ev)
{
    var name = ev.data.getName();
    var definition = ev.data.definition;

    if (name == 'image')
    {
        definition.onOk = function(e)
        {
            console.log( e );
        };
    }
});
```

Awesome, unless now the default behavior is dropped, resulting in no image being added to the CK content.

Checking up on [CK's source](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L327), I do not want to break 74 lines worth of functionality provided by default.

My goal is to simply run the image through a callback after it has been appended.

Is copy/paste, modify the only way to retain extend the functionality, or is there another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Small improvement of maximkou's solution:

```
var oldImplementation = definition.onOk;
definition.onOk = function( e ) {
    oldImplementation.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments ) );
    console.log( e );
};
```

This solution is <s>ok and AFAIK it's the cleanest one</s>.

**Update**: I've found a better solution - there's [`dialog#ok`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-event-ok) event about which I've just learnt :). So you don't need to change dialog's definition - you can bind your event listener like this:

```
editor.on('dialogShow', function ( evt ) {
    if ( evt.data.getName() == 'image' ) {
        var listener = evt.data.on( 'ok', function() {
            console.log( 'ok!' );
        } );

        // We need to remove that listener, to avoid duplicating it on
        // next dialogShow.
        evt.data.on( 'hide', function() {
            listener.removeListener();
        } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: I did try a similar approach before (`oI(e)` and `oI.call(e)`), but had errors coming my way.

Comment: `oI.call(e)` will work like `e.oI()`. But you want to call the old `onOk` method as it was property of original `definition` object.

Comment: @Reinmar Thanks for the update. Where does `editor` come from? I overload dialogs according to [the CKEditor documentation](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7526/_samples/api_dialog.html) using `CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {if (ev.data.name == 'link') {//...}});` but there's no `editor` and obviously I can't use `CKEDITOR`. That's why I use `ev.data.definition.dialog.on('show', function(evt) {this.on('ok', function() {//...})})` but that seems to have another context (this) than the original `'onOk()'`.

Comment: `editor` comes from wherever you want :). For example you can use `CKEDITOR.instances` object or value returned from `CKEDITOR.replace/inline`. Note that my answer explains the way to add this behaviour for one, specific editor, not globally. `CKEDITOR#dialogDefinition` object is global.

Answer (score 2):

```
var oldImplementation = definition.onOk;
definition.onOk = function(e)
{
    oldImplementation(e);
    console.log( e );
};
```