# Is it safe to hook into insertElement event?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This is closely related to [Image dialog — extend onOk, instead of total overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922424/image-dialog-extend-onok-instead-of-total-overwrite), just that I thought of another solution:

```
editor.on('insertElement', function (ev)
{
    var element = ev.data.$;

    if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'IMG')
    {
         // do stuff with element
    }
});
```

This works perfectly.

The problem with this solution, though, is that in [CKEditor's Docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-insertElement) it says:

> Internal event to perform the insertElement call.

Is it safe to rely on internal event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit risky to rely on this event, although I'm pretty sure that it won't be changed in minor release, because we are avoiding such changes.

But it may be modified in some future major release. For example in CKEditor 4.0 we were forced to modify [`editor#insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-insertHtml) and [`editor#paste`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) breaking their backward compatibility. However, `editor#paste` is a normal, public event, so as you can see - everything may change if there's no other, clean way to solve some design problem.

Thus, I think that you can rely on this event, but just as with every other piece of API - major release can bring some necessary changes.

PS. Overwriting dialog definition's `onOk` method is a better solution.

**Update**: In my opinion the insertXXX events trio is incorrectly documented as internal. There's nothing internal about them and they are very useful in similar cases. We'll perhaps change their descriptions.

Comment: Not afraid of changes, the project that's utilizing CK here is a constantly growing, updating one. But yes, I'll check the `onOk` method once again and opt for that one. OT: Any estimate on 4.2? Our project really needs **Tab** indent support, saw it coming our way for 4.2, but couldn't find any estimates.

Comment: Nothing is set yet, but we definitely need/want to close 4.2 in a month. It is currently blocked by the widget feature which is massive. But you can always get the patch (it's ready and on review), apply it and build your own CKEditor package.