# ckeditor event change the link when press ok on dialog link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

hi on dialog link of ckeditor  i want to add a attribute to the link when the user click ok.
is it Possible?
This is my code:

```
var oldImplementation = dialogDefinition.onOk;
dialogDefinition.onOk = function (e) {
    oldImplementation.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Comment: See the similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922424/image-dialog-extend-onok-instead-of-total-overwrite/16924233#16924233

Comment: What have you tried? Or do you want to know how to get a reference to the link node? That code does not show anything related to the inserted element.